# How is it safe to pass an object from an interpreted language like VBA or Python over to some other code running on a different cpu core?

Tags: python, vba, multithreading, multiprocessing, interpreter

I have recently seen an example of some VBA code (which is an interpreted language) which defines and passes an object to a python process, and that python executes methods on the VBA object.

The exact code isn't important, buy my understanding of the process is that it goes like this:

- VBA interpreter runs in one thread, initialises the object and passes it to the python process
- Python is running in a separate process on a separate thread (maybe even separate core of the CPU)
- At some point python calls a method of the alien VBA object
- This must then call the VBA interpreter to execute the method

I don't understand how this doesn't lead to crashes; the VBA interpreter running on thread 1 needs to be invoked by another thread. Why is it safe for a second thread to access the interpreter, won't it interrupt something and lead to corrupted state? What is synchronising things?

Python is also interpreted and must have similar problems; if it passes an object to a totally unaware process eg some C# exe that doesn't know the inner workings of python and will attempt to access the interpreter without any of the nice mutexes and locking to make it safe. VBA is an old language which does not support writing of multithreaded code, so is there some other mechanism protecting the interpreter from calls from multiple cores at once?

Comment: Re, "Python is running in a separate process on a separate thread" Once you've crossed a process boundary, the fact that you've also crossed a thread boundary becomes completely irrelevant. Everything that is interesting about multi-threaded programming is connected to the fact that different threads in the same process share the same virtual address space. But threads in different processes _don't_ share the same address space. When you cross a process boundary, it becomes a multi-processing problem, and _not_ a multi-threading problem.

Comment: Relevant: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/66895371/8488913](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66895371/8488913)