# Does VBA use a Global Interpreter Lock? Do all interpreted languages need one?

Tags: vba, multithreading, mutex, interpreter, gil

It is possible to pass a VBA class (COM object) from one hosted VBA process to another (e.g. one instance of Excel.exe to another) using the `Application.Run` method. That means the second process (thread 2) will have access to code defined in the first process (thread 1).

It is therefore possible that the second thread would invoke a method on the object from thread 1 which runs using the first thread's interpreter, **so thread 1's interpreter is being invoked from thread 1 and thread 2 simultaneously.**

---

That's probably not surprising to anyone, but it was to me, since VBA is implemented as a single threaded language (it all runs in the host application's UI thread!) and doesn't give you syntax to write multithreaded code. Based on that I thought surely the VBA interpreter wouldn't be thread safe and would not allow execution from other threads. But apparently you can, and I've also passed VBA objects to python libraries in the past (which I imagine run on a separate thread with the python interpreter).

So how is it done, does VBA have a GIL like Python - meaning the interpreter can only ever be run by a single thread at a time, or is there something else going on? Is there any way to check?

Comment: No, VBA relies on the threading guarantees provided by the STA apartment it creates.  Calls from worker threads (not created by VBA) are automatically marshaled to the VBA main thread.  In effect pretty similar to the JavaScript execution model.

Comment: @HansPassant so the synchronisation comes from the com proxy blocking thread 2 until it posts and receives a message from thread 1?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

To control what threads can access methods on a COM Object (thread affinity), COM uses apartments. An apartment is a place for objects having the same thread affinity. Apartments are specific to a single process.

VBA Objects have high thread affinity and they “live” in an STA (single threaded apartment). They will receive calls from a single thread which is always the same thread. In VBA there is one and only one thread in the STA. STA is designed to protect objects against concurrency. A hidden window is created when a thread enters an STA (CoInitializeEx is called). When a call to an object living in the STA is made, a window message is posted to the hidden window which then makes the thread in the apartment to execute the call. If two threads call methods on an object living in an STA, then the hidden window will receive two messages and only one will be handled at a time meaning that the second is blocked until the first call has completed. In short, objects living in an STA do not have concurrency.

A call from another process is not a direct call. Different apartments and threads. COM simulates a synchronous call instead. The call in the calling process is paused and then replayed in the process where the actual object lives. COM is designed to work with objects even from different computers. The simulation (or interception) involves a proxy and a stub and the COM transport.

For example, if a VBA thread (T1) in process 1 uses an object created in a VBA thread in process 2 (T2), then the object’s interface is exported from the apartment of T2 to the apartment of T1 (the interface is marshalled). When COM marshals the interface, it creates a stub living in the apartment of T2. The stub represents the calling side - T1. The marshalled information is transported and then used to create (unmarshall) the object’s interface (the proxy) in the apartment of T1. Communication is set between the proxy and the stub. So, T1 receives a proxy, not the true object (which lives in a totally different memory space). When T1 calls a method on the proxy, COM forwards the call to the real object via the stub, waits until the call is done and returns the result.